# when (1+bx)^5 is expanded the coefficient of x is equal to the coefficient of x^2. Find the value of b when b is not equal to zero

Tags: binomial-theorem

> When $$(1+bx)^5$$ is expanded the coefficient of $x$ is equal to the coefficient of $x^2$. Find the value of $b$ when $b$ is not equal to zero

I tried to solve it by using the $T_{r+1}$ formula as well as the binomial theorem formula. But I just can't understand this. Anyone help

Comment: 1) using binomial theorem, compute the coefficient of $x$ (it is a polynomial in $b$). 2) compute the coefficient of $x^2$, 3) equate them. Which part you are stuck?

Comment: What was the problem with the binomial theorem?

Comment: I was stuck on the second part

Comment: Look at Karn's answer, the coefficient for $x^2$ is $\binom{5}{2}b^2$.

Comment: Yup thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily notice that
$$[x]=\binom51b^1=5b$$
and
$$\left[x^2\right]=\binom52b^2=10b^2$$

Therefore,
$$5b=10b^2$$
Since $b\ne0$,
$$5=10b$$
giving
$$b=\frac12$$

---

For verification,

$$(1+0.5x)^5=0.03125 x^5 + 0.3125 x^4 + 1.25 x^3 + \color{red}{2.5} x^2 + \color{red}{2.5} x + 1$$

Comment: Thank you so much. This helped me

Answer (score 2):

According to the Taylor polynomial expansion of $$ f(x)= (1+bx)^5$$ we get

$$ f(x)= f(0)+f'(0)x+f"(0) x^2/{2!}+...+f^{(5)}(0) x^5/{5!}$$

$$ f(x)= (1+bx)^5 \implies \\f'(0)=5b, f''(0)/2=10 b^2$$

$$ 5b=10b^2 \implies b=1/2$$